# Ionic won't refresh anything

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

It's been a lost day of work and I feel very frustrated.
It's been some time since I been able to run my app on my device and get it to work properly.
Whats happening is that everytime do ***cordova run --device*** it will always show an older version.
I updated the version in ***config.xml***, did ***cordova prepare***, uninstalled previous version of the app, clear data and cache.
I don't know what Im doing grong, should I run it some other way? I also searched for answers on other topics but none seems to work for me.

Currently Im running ***Ionic 3.6.0, Cordova 7.0.1 and npm 5.3.0***
Please guys, give me a hand because Im running out of time with this development!

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Solved with

```
ionic cordova run android --livereload --device
```